# Страница дергается при загрузке

Tags: javascript, html, css

При загрузке страницы http://176.112.192.242:4678/ и переходе по внутренним ссылкам страница сначала немного сжимает шрифт на 1-2 секунды, а потом восстанавливает нужный размер. Это создает дергания при просмотре. Проявялется только в хроме. В чемможет быть дело?

Comment: Посмотрите в консоли на ошибки. Исправьте их. GET http://176.112.192.242:4678/images/logo.png 404 (Not Found)
logo.png:1 GET http://176.112.192.242:4678/images/logo.png 404 (Not Found)
combine.js?load=6T!(!)!q1H6V!j6W0r601K610u6563!Q*fq5QlQnQbQdQcQ2QeQfQgQYQ4Q7Q$Q0Q5Q8Q-Q3q-Q1Q6Q9Q_Q…:146 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null

Comment: а это вылетает при отладке 'Failed to execute 'matches' on 'Element': '[s!='']:x' is not a valid selector.' Проверьте селекторы